# How to handle the missing arguments while executing .pl file in PERL?

Tags: perl

I have .pl file and i have to execute the .pl file using 2 arguments. If user not entering the two arguments, how can i handle the error for not passing those 2 arguments ?

Answer (score 6):

```
die "Usage: $0 <first> <second>\n" unless @ARGV == 2;
my ($first, $second) = @ARGV;
```

*(Note the `\n`: I prevent perl from appending the "at line nnn")*

That said, I always try to come up with some sane defaults for missing arguments in my scripts (e.g. no output file given => print to STDOUT, etc).

You should also probably take a look at [Getopt::Long](http://search.cpan.org/~jv/Getopt-Long-2.38/lib/Getopt/Long.pm).

Answer (score 0):

However you like. Tradition is to use a default value or exit with an error status (i.e. not 0) while printing a summary of the invokation part of the application's instructions to STDERR.

Answer (score 0):

```
  if($#ARGV == -1) { print "No arguments are passsed" }
    if($#ARGV == 0) {print "SINGLE argument" }
```

In Perl you have special array `@ARGV` which holds all the passed arguments.  To access them you can use `ARGV[0]` .....`ARGV[n]`

Comment: You should probably `die` rather than just `print` if the problem prevents the program from running successfully.  A common idiom is `die "Usage: $0 param1 param2\n" unless (@ARGV == 2);`

Comment: @tripleee: ouch, you've been faster. You should have answered instead of commenting!

Comment: yes tripleee your absolutely right but i concentrated on @ARGV concept

Comment: Not exactly a challenging question anyway (-: